Best practice for branch-n-price to solve scheduling problems
Recently, I asked on how to decompose my model with the Dantzig-Wolfe reformulation (see here). I implemented the model and subsequently solved it with column generation. However, since this approach only performs column generation on the root node, this approach is only a heuristic. Now I was wondering how to solve it optimally. I know that I can do this using a branch-n-price approach. As I am not currently familiar with branch-n price, I was wondering what general branching rules are? I have read about the Ryan/Foster branching rule, but I don't know if it is the right one for my model.
I suppose branching at $\lambda$ is the way to go, but how do I determine which fractional $\lambda$ to branch at?
Are there any other things I need to be aware of?

I suggest taking a look at the Branch-and-Price book by Desrosiers et al., it has a chapter on branching rules.
Branching on single master variables is generally inefficient and difficult to incorporate into the pricing problem (note that you will need to take the duals of the branching constraints into account on the redcost). Regarding the inefficiency, it leads to very unbalanced trees - one of the branches is very limiting, and the other is almost not limiting at all.
What I'm doing in my work is adding set-covering/knapsack constraints to the master problem, based on fractional pricing variables. It seems to work well enough for my case, and it's not difficult to add the branching dual values. I think this approach also appears in the book I mentioned.

Thank you for your answer. May I ask you which programming language you use to solve your problems?

I'm using Python (PySCIPOpt)

Thanks. Do you know if there is a publicly available implementation of BnP?

@mingabua There is a pretty extensive exercise here. The exercises are about adding simple things, so the PySCIPOPt-specific structure (which I guess is what you care about) is already there.
